# Show that $g$ is differentiable at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g(x)=x^2-f(x)$. If $g(x),f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in \mathcal{R}$, show that $g$ is differentiable at $0$.

I am stuck at this problem for long. I feel if we can prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, then we can prove that $g$ is too. But how to proceed. Can someone please help.

Is it still true if only $g(x)\ge 0$ ?

Comment: This is false, though.  Are you supposed to assume that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: @Randall; no we are not

Comment: Take a discontinuous $f$ at $0$.  If $g$ were differentiable there, then from $f(x) = x^2-g(x)$ you would have that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, but it's not even continuous there.

Comment: @Randall $f(x)+g(x)=x^2$ and $f,g\geq0$ together makes them both differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  Good eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to showing that if $0 \le g(x) \le x^2$ for all $x$ then $g$ is differentiable at $0$.
But this implies that $g(0) = 0$ and
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \left|\frac{g(t) - g(0)}{t}\right| \le \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2}{t} = 0.
$$